When did iterating on the span of an array become faster than iterating on the array itself
In this recent video by Nick Chapsas at the end he commented that the Find method on List<T> was "unoptimized" because the code doesn't iterate on the Span of the array, but on the array itself:
public T? Find(Predicate<T> match) {
    if (match == null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
        if (match(_items[i])) {
            return _items[i];
        }
    }
    return default;
}

I thought that iterating on spans can be made as fast as on arrays (but not faster) from this paragraph of the (updated?) blogpost  by Stephen Toub on Spans:

The assembly code is so similar in part because of the elimination of
bounds checks. But also relevant is the JIT’s recognition of the span
indexer as an intrinsic, meaning that the JIT generates special code
for the indexer, rather than translating its actual IL code into
assembly.
All of this is to illustrate that the runtime can apply for spans the
same kinds of optimizations it does for arrays, making spans an
efficient mechanism for accessing data.

When did it become self-evident that iterating on the Span of an array would be as fast and maybe faster than just iterating on the array itself? What .NET version introduced these JIT Span optimizations that couldn't be used for arrays?

Github is a good start, I don't think all the optimizations happened at once. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7589 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43549 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77032 https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/93144

Is that really what he said, though? As far as I remeber he said using Predicate<T> is outdated and he was surprised to find it not being replaced by Func<T, bool> , right?

There is no real difference between Predicate<T> and Func<T, bool>. Both are delegates with the very same signature and in sense of perfomance there is no difference.

The reason, why Find() is slower, than the foreach(Span) is because within Find() the bounce check has to be done every time when _items[i] is called, because i could be out of bounds. By iterating with foreach on a Span the bounds check can be omitted, because it is done once when the span is created.

@Oliver sure. I was just reiterating what I heard him say in the video. And that was something like "I am surprised to still see Predicate being used here ..."

Seen it too. I think the reason is backward compatibility, cause when someone is working with reflection on it, it would be a breaking change.

@Oliver, exactly what I was thinking while watching the video. "If it ain't broke - don't fix it" :D

But while the public signature should (probably) not being changed and stay with Predicate, the implementation itself could be improved and could also use Span. My guess is, it was simply overseen and will be done in the near future.

That's what Nick was kind of suspecting, too. However, he was less confident about it.

Iterating over a span has two advantages here:

it avoids an indirection into a field (rather than a local) for the array
the span's length is known in a predictable way

If it wasn't for _size also being in play, it might be possible to fix the code; i.e. given:
for(int i = 0 ; i < _arr.Length ; i++)
{
    DoSomething(_arr[i]);
}

simply hoisting _arr into a local allows the JIT to elide the bounds checks, because the array can't be reassigned:
var arr = _arr;
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++)
{
    DoSomething(arr[i]);
}

Note also that both foreach (var x in _arr) and foreach (var x in arr) would be fine and allow the bounds checks to be elided. However, the pesky _size means that the bounds checks cannot be elided, and if the _size doesn't match _arr.Length (oversized buffers), we can't use simple foreach. Span fixes this indirectly, because the span is bounded; creating a span of length _size means that once the span has been constructed (with bounds validation in the constructor) the JIT can trust it, and elide the bounds checks.

So concerning the question, my take-away is: The optimization would have been possible even without Span<T> because it's not about that but about a "sideeffect" while using it, right? (Mind blown, btw.)

The optimization is not really possible without Span<T> because the length of the underlying used array and the used elements (in public Count, in private _size) you can't remove the bounds check within the loop. By doing it only once through creation of the span you gain the performance.

@Fildor if we were iterating the entire array, the optimization would have been possible without Span<T>; for partial iteration: span is great

Again and again it fascinates me how much effect these little subtleties can have. And then I start to wonder how often I messed up at something like this but the actual effect was too small to be recognized.

@MarcGravell I just can't wrap my head around how is the "partial vs full" iteration relevant here.

@IvanPetrov the JIT compiler is able to detect certain patterns and remove the bounds checks; this includes iterations in the range [0,length) on arrays and spans, but in this case we're using a range that isn't the known length. Imagine that _size could be larger than the array length - this should error. Because the JIT compiler can't prove to itself that it cannot ever go out-of-range, it needs to include range checks.

@MarcGravell aren't spans and arrays behaving the same when we don't know the length of the range, i.e. _size? I thought you were alluding to some optimization that always takes place if we for example use Slice() so we have < span.Length instead of some magic number that the JITter cannot always prove is within the bounds of the array, i.e. <42

@Ivan if you slice, and then iterate the entire slice: the JIT can prove in advance that we won't ever go out of bounds. That's the entire point. The slice operation does the single range check of the upper bound - after that: golden
